# recorrer objeto bidimensional con vuejs

Tags: javascript, vue.js

estoy intentando traer los datos de un array de post  los cuales vienen con sus respectivos comentarios, pero no logro acceder a los comentarios a traves de vuejs. con laravel simplemente hacia un foreach aninado y era suficiente pero en este caso veo que no da los mismos resultados.
app.js
primero obtengo los resultados

```
app = new Vue({
el: '#crud',
created:function(){
    this.getPost();
},
data: {
    posts:[],
},
methods:{
    getPost:function(){
        let url = 'post';
        axios.get(url).then(response =>{
            this.posts = response.data
        })
    }
}
```

})

```
{

     "posts": [
        {
          "id": 27,
          "title": "soy anonimo",
          "body": "anonimus",
          "image": null,
          "is_anon": 1,
          "user_id": 3,
          "created_at": "2020-05-13T22:50:04.000000Z",
          "updated_at": "2020-05-13T22:50:04.000000Z",
          "comment": [
            {
              "id": 2,
              "comment": "saludos",
              "date_comment": "0000-00-00",
              "time_comment": "00:00:00",
              "user_id": 1,
              "post_id": 27,
              "created_at": null,
              "updated_at": null
            }
          ]
        },


      ]
    }
```

en la vista intente esto:

```
<div id="crud">
    <p v-for="post in posts">
        @{{post.title}}

        <p v-for="comment in post.comment">
            @{{comment.comment}}
        </p>

    </p>
</div>
```

pero no hay caso , no puedo acceder a los comentarios, como podria logarlo?

al escribir en la vista

```
 <div id="crud">
<p v-for="post in posts">
    @{{post.title}}
    @{{post.comment}}
</p>
</pre>
```

obtengo:

```
miTitulo [ { "id": 3, "comment": "eres un titulo", "date_comment": "0000-00-00", "time_comment": "00:00:00", "user_id": 1, "post_id": 7, "created_at": null, "updated_at": null } ]
```

al agregar en la vista  @{{post.comment[0]}}  ([0])

```
miTitulo  { "id": 3, "comment": "eres un titulo", "date_comment": "0000-00-00", "time_comment": "00:00:00", "user_id": 1, "post_id": 7, "created_at": null, "updated_at": null }
```

seria el mismo resultado pero con los corchetes. 
entonces quedaria acceder asi

```
@{{post.comment[0].id}}
```

pero al apuntar al id (o cualquier otro atributo recibo el error)

```
Error in render: "TypeError: post.comment[0] is undefined"
```

Comment: ¿Estás seguro que es la vista? Después de obtener los datos, si los imprimes por consola, ¿los tienes? ¿Has pensado la posibilidad de que estés intentando renderizar los datos antes de que la petición HTTP se resuelva?

Comment: El título del post sí lo imprime?  Te dá algún error?

Comment: el titulo del post me lo resuelve correctamente y si pongo @{{post.comment}} me da el array con los comentarios, solo que no puedo iterarlos..

Comment: Qué pasa si en el `.then` de la llamada axios pones `this.posts = response.data.posts`?

Comment: Qué pasa si en el .then de la llamada axios pones this.posts = response.data.posts .
Me devuelve {}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Editado

Ya que tienes doble array bidimensional, uno dentro del otro.

Lo puedes hacer de la siguiente manera:

```html
<div id="crud">
    <div v-for="post in posts">
        @{{post.title}}

        <p v-for="comment in post.comment">
            @{{comment.comment}}
        </p>

    </div>
</div>
```

Me falto añadir que en tu código javascript tienes un pequeño error.

Estas usando la instancia `this` a un nivel que no puede ser heredada, lo recomendable es guardar en una nueva variable la instancia para que no te de problemas.

Así:

```
app = new Vue({
  el: '#crud',
  created: function () {
    this.getPost();
  },
  data: {
    posts:[],
  },
  methods:{
    getPost: function () {
        const _self = this;
        let url = 'post';
        axios.get(url).then(response => {
            _self.posts = response.data.posts
        })
    }
  }
})
```

Comment: @xDonYeyox he editado mi respuesta después de percatarme de un ligero error que tenias en tu código.

Comment: puede que quizás ese haya sido el error desde un principio